# "Partial" matching IDs in two dataframes and merging in R

Tags: r, string-matching, partial

Some of the data I have been working on is re-ID'd several times.
To work on them efficiently, I need to merge `df1` and `df2` according to their `id`s.
I have tried several approaches based on `separate()`, `grep()`, `fuzzy_join()` but because of `id2` of `df2` contains longer ids than `df1` I couldn't manage to deal with this issue.

Representative `df1` and `df2` below;

```
View(df1)

      id1   value1
    N12800  19562
    N11901  403
    N14688  100
    N12886B 32
    T00014  14
    T16487  13


View(df2)

          id2                            value2
N11959_N11901                              56
T03938_N16439_T05162_T05141_N14997         654
N12800                                     1234
N12886B_N12886A                            75
N14688                                     14
T18332_T16487_T13537_T11268_T09399         61
```

Can you suggest a solution for this "partial" ID matching problem

Answer (score 1):

If you tried `separate()`, you are already familiar with `tidyr`. Does lengthening `df2` give you what you need to perform the join?

```
unnest(
  mutate(
    test,
    id2 = strsplit(id2, split = "_")
  ),
  id2
)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion but unfortunately it's not helping in this case. Because df2 is actually too wide (dim 250x57213), I was planning to find common names between df1 &df2 and replacing the id names on df2 orderly. I know that all ids available in both data but in a messy way in df2.

Comment: `df2 <- mutate(df2, index = row_number());`

`df3 <- select(df2, index, id2) %>%
  mutate(id2 = strsplit(id2, split = "_")) %>%
  tidyr::unnest(id2)`

Join df1 to df3 by `id2`, then join the resulting object to df2 by `index`

Comment: Thank you so much! I couldn't simply think of this approach to solve my problem. You've made my day!